# if check box checked active text field PHP

Tags: php

1. first textfield should be disabled and when i clicked on check box, textfield should be active.

   ```
   echo'<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"/>';
   echo'<textarea name="explain" id="explain"
   cols="" rows="" style="width:300 ;height:300"></textarea>

   if(isset($_POST['checkbox']))
   {
     ??? 
   }
   ```

Comment: I think you want javascript for that, not PHP.

Comment: Will request to php to be used as client side for you... : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use this:

```
  <form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" onchange="toggleDisabled(this.checked)"/>
    <textarea name="explain" id="explain"></textarea>
    </form>

    <script>
    function toggleDisabled(checked) {
        document.getElementById('explain').disabled = checked ? false : true;
    }
    </script>
```

Full code is [here](http://plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/enable-disable.php)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/bbymkcua/ the disabled/active doesn't toggle

Comment: hope this link can help you- http://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/enable-disable.php

Answer (score 1):

<sub>**Your question a little unclear. I've interpreted this as you needing JavaScript to set the `textarea` to disabled and active on a checkbox value without going to the server.**</sub>

Using Javascript you can add an event listener on the checkbox and check the `checked` property, then set the `textarea` to `disabled` or not.

```js
document.getElementById("checkbox").addEventListener("click", checkbox_textarea);
function checkbox_textarea() {
   if( this.checked == true ) {
       document.getElementById("textarea").disabled = false;
       return false;
   }
   document.getElementById("textarea").disabled = true; 
}
```

```html
<input id=checkbox type=checkbox name=chk /> Enable text area <br />
<textarea id=textarea name=txt cols=50 rows=20 disabled></textarea>
```

Comment: your answer is true but does not work in my console! i've put above code in script tag